# One view with different looks - MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have a MVC project. The views are aspx.

I created a view split in one vertical line. The left side is always the same, it doesn't change. On the left side, there are two buttons. If I click on button1, the right part should have a form for entering food. If I click on button2, the right part should have a form for entering drink. The forms have very different look.

I already made the part about the food and it works. I put the form in a table in a div which is named "food", and it is hidden always except when button1 is clicked.

Now I have to do the part for the drinks. I want to do the same thing for that, but I have a problem. When I made the food form, I went to design view of the aspx page and it was very easy, I saw what I was doing visually. Now, if I go to design view (to make the drink part), the part of the food is already shown. How to put controls over the one I already have? How to position the drink form above the food form? It's div would have an id named 'drinkSide' and I will switch between the drinks and the foods.

Is there another way except with new view?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create the separate pages partial views, and register them both to the containing page.  This would keep them nicely separate.

Comment: But I already made the food part. Can I just copy it? Can you pls explain a little further?

Comment: Yes, you could move all the existing markup into the partial view.  I'm not entirely sure how partial views are implemented in ASP.MVC 2.0, but I imagine you create User controls (ascx files).

Answer (score 1):

You could use AJAX if you don't like showing hiding divs. The idea is that you will put the 2 forms in 2 separate partial views: `food.ascx` and `drink.ascx`. Initially you will have a div element in the main view which will be used as a placeholder for the form. When button1 is clicked you could send an AJAX request to a controller action which will return the first partial and you would inject the resulting partial HTML into the container div. You could do the same for the second button except that you would call a different controller action returning the second partial.